# Is a linked stylesheet from Content-Disposition: inline; safe for HTML mails?

Tags: html, css, email, attachment

right now I'm using `<style>` to add the CSS classes to my HTML emails. It is a pretty big block at the top and now I'm wondering if I it is safe to add a stylesheet via `<link>` which is embedded in the mail as attachment.

I already tried that and it works fine, but I'm not sure if it is safe and supported everywhere. Does anyone of you know?

I found this page which shows that `<style>` is mostly supported but  is not, is that correct? https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/style-element/style-in-body/
https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/

This is how it would be added:

```
<link href="cid:STYLESHEET" rel="stylesheet" />
```

And below:

```
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="STYLESHEET.css"
Content-ID: <STYLESHEET>
... (base64 encoded CSS)
```